# How to find the angle between 2 3D vectors, using basic trigonometry and geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, vectors, proof-explanation

Using spherical coordinates, I was trying to prove the following dot product formula for 2 3D vectors:

> $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\cos(\psi)$
>
> where $\psi$ is the angle between the vectors

My approach was:

$
\vec{u}=<u\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\phi_1), u\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\phi_1), u\cos(\theta_1)>
$

$
\vec{v}=<v\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\phi_2), v\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\phi_2), v\cos(\theta_2)>
$

$
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\bigg[\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\phi_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\phi_2)+\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\phi_2)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\bigg]
$

$
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\bigg[\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\Big(\cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)+\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)\Big)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\bigg]
$

$
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\bigg[\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\bigg]
$

$
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\bigg[\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\Delta\phi)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\bigg]
$

Upon reaching this stage, I was unsure what to do. The expression in the square brackets should evaluate to the cos of the angle between the two vectors. I decided that I needed to evaluate an expression for this angle (in terms of $\phi_1, \phi_2, \theta_1$ and $\theta_2$) to continue with this proof. How could this be done without dot/cross product?

Alternatively, how would the trigonometric expression in the brackets be reduced to a single cosine function?

Comment: Not all angles exist on the same plane so you won't get the desired angles from the given information.

Comment: How do you know you have proved the cosine rule for the angle between vectors? What is the angle between two vectors defined in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Any two non-parallel vectors determine a plane. So instead of trying to prove this in 3 dimensions, prove it in 2 dimensions, where the angle between the two vextors is easy to calculate, instead of being a much more difficult calculation that what you are trying to prove from it.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I have the magnitude of both vectors multiplied by each other multiplied by a trigonometric expression. If this can be written in terms of a single cosine, and I haven't made any mistakes (which is likely as a rookie), wouldn't that map to the formula $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors?

If I made no mistakes, I'm assuming that the expression in the brackets would evaluate to be the cosine of the angle between two vectors in spherical coordinates, no?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I managed to prove the 2 dimensional alternative previously. However, I wanted to prove whether this extends to the 3 dimensional case as well.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou So there is no 3D geometry or 3D Pythagoras/Trigonometry which can evaluate an expression for this angle?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Sorry, for the confusion. I'm not trying to prove the cosine rule ($a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$), but rather just the formula $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\cos(\Delta\theta)$, where $\Delta\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: You will not be able to go from $u\cdot v$ to $\|u\|\|v\|\cos\theta$ in spherical coordinates unless you *already* have a formula for $\theta$ (or at least $\cos\theta$) using spherical coordinates, which you do not. In 2D, you can say something like $\theta=\beta-\alpha$, where the angles $\alpha,\beta$ describe $u,v$ in polar coordinates. You do not have anything like this in 3D. Spherical coordinates is not the way to go. (The way to go is using symmetry and invariance, I'd say.)

Comment: I believed this to be a definition, not a theorema.

Comment: @Dominique - You can define the inner product in this way. It is usually considered preferable to do so, since the other common definition is dependent on a coordinate system. However, there *is* another common definition. Further, that definition is older, arising independently in both the predecessors lo the concept of vectors. So this formula was a theorem before it was ever a definition

Comment: @MrChickenNuggetBadman - My point is that in $n$-dimensions, no matter how big $n > 1$ is, the problem **always** reduces to the 2-dimensional version, because the two vectors **always** lie in some plane. This means that what you need to do is to show that you can choose two vectors in the plane (any orthogonal unit vectors will do) to establish coordinates in that plane, such that the 2D inner product they define agrees with the original inner product. Then your 2D proof shows the $n$D result. This is a far easier approach than what you are attempting.

Comment: As for your approach, first *do not call the angle between the vectors "$\Delta\theta$"*. That angle is not a difference between two values of the $\theta$ coordinate you've already established. That works in 2D only. Give your angle a different name, such as $\alpha$ or $\psi$. Now realize that this angle has a very complex relationship with $\theta_1, \phi_1, \theta_2, \phi_2$, and even figuring out what that relationship is, is difficult to do. Yes, you can look it up, but that risks it having been proved using the result you are trying to show (as it usually is), makne the logic circular.

Comment: Use the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input in the comments and thank you especially to @Somos.

The current result was given as:

$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\Bigg[\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\phi_1−\phi_2)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)\Bigg]$

As given by @Somos, the spherical law of cosines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) can be used to further simplify this trigonometric expression.

> [image: Spherical Law of Cosines]
>
> $\cos(c)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)\cos(C)$
>
> Spherical Law of Cosines

2 random vectors were plotted on https://www.math3d.org/, with their tails at the centre of a sphere.

Here is how they came out (with hand drawing above it):

[image: Two random vectors]

By comparing both images, it can be seen that the angle C is analogous to $\Delta\phi$:

> $\cos(c)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)\cos(\Delta\phi)$

a, b and c are analogous to $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\psi$. This is assuming that the angles are in radians so the length of the arc on the unit sphere is the same as the angle subtending that arc.

> $\cos(\psi)=\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\cos(\Delta\phi)$

Therefore it can be proved that, indeed:

> $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=uv\cos(\psi)$
>
> where $\psi$ is the angle between the vectors, on the same plane.

Comment: Sorry for my articulation was a bit hard to understand . Quite an abstract concept to explain.